# What is the difference between these statements in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new in C. What is the difference between these:

```
a = b;
```

and

```
*a = *b;
```

(Assume both are integer pointers.)

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but it looks like the second uses pointers (and the first does not). Where are you getting that both are pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Both are similar in that both statements assigns the value on the right-hand side to the left-hand side.

With

```
a = b;
```

you make `a` point to the same place where `b` is pointing. You now have two pointers to the same location.

For example, lets say we have the following setup:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

int *a = &x;  // Make a point to the variable x
int *b = &y;  // Make b point to the variable y
```

Then if you do

```
a = b;
```

both `a` and `b` will be pointing to the variable `y`.

---

With

```
*a = *b;
```

(assuming both `a` and `b` are pointing somewhere valid) you assign the value of *where* `b` is pointing to *where* `a` is pointing.

If you understand arrays, it might be easier to see the last assignment as

```
a[0] = b[0];
```

It's doing exactly the same thing as `*a = *b`.

Taking the same example as above:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

int *a = &x;  // Make a point to the variable x
int *b = &y;  // Make b point to the variable y
```

Then after

```
*a = *b;
```

the value of `x` and `y` will be the same, and it will be `20`.

Answer (score 1):

First let's assume the following declarations:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int *a = &x;
int *b = &y;
```

After this, all of the following are true:

```
 a == &x       // int * == int *
*a ==  x == 1  // int   == int   == int
 b == &y       // int * == int *
*b ==  y == 2  // int   == int   == int
```

After `a = b`, then the following are true:

```
 a == &y
*a ==  y == 2
 b == &y       
*b ==  y == 2
```

We have assigned the value of `b` to `a`, so now `a` and `b` both point to `y`.

If instead you had written `*a = *b`, then we would have

```
 a == &x
*a ==  x == 2
 b == &y       
*b ==  y == 2
```

Instead of pointing `a` to `y`, we have assigned the value of the object that `b` *points to* (`y`) into the object that `a` points to (`x`), so now both `x` and `y` have the value `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following guide out as it pretty much answers your question:

[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are no difference in a=b and *a= *b.Both are same.Here a and b is point different element.

When you write the statement:

```
*a=*b
```

That means that the value of pointing element of b is assigned in a. And when you write this statement:

```
a=b
```

that means address of an element which is contain by b is now assigned in a. So those are same.

Here the code for better understanding:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=10,y=20;
    int *a,*b;
    a=&x;
    b=&y;
    a=b;
    cout<<*a<<" "<<*b<<endl;
    a=&x;
    b=&y;//for change the value of a and b we assign again
    cout<<*a<<" "<<*b<<endl;
    *a = *b;
    cout<<*a<<" "<<*b<<endl;

}
```